# Custom Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder not recognized in an integration springboot test

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-test

All

I have customized `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` in my main Spring Boot application class as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Autowired
public void configureJackson(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    builder.filters( new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter( "customFilter", new ExampleFilter() ) );
}
```

where `ExampleFilter` is an extension of `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`.
My POJOs are annotated with Jackson's `@JsonFilter("customFilter")`. 

I have exposed the POJOs over HTTP using `@RestController` and `@GetMapping` annotations.
This works fine and the custom filter gets invoked when I run the application and access the end point.

Now I have an integration test written as below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getUser() throws Exception {
        POJO obj = this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.port + "/pojo", POJO.class);

        Assertions.assertThat(obj).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(obj.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Jane");
        Assertions.assertThat(obj.getLastName()).isEqualTo("Doe");
        Assertions.assertThat(obj.getAge()).isEqualTo("24");
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the obj comes as null and I see an error that `no FilterProvider configured`

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'customFilter'; no FilterProvider configured; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'customFilter'; no FilterProvider configured
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I correct this?

My folder structure is :
src/main/java/com/a/b/c/Application.java
src/main/java/com/a/b/c/controller/ControllerA.java

src/test/java/com/a/b/c/controller/IntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by configuring `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` in a slightly different way in the main application file as shown below. But I still don't know why the Autowiring approach isn't working.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.filters( new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter( "customFilter", new ExampleFilter() ) );
    return builder;
}
```

I'd still like to know that in the test context, why the auto configured `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` isn't picked up for customization while replacing it with `@Bean` works.